# Можно ли зарегистрировать пользователя в телеграм через код?

Tags: python, telegram

Всем привет, есть ли какой-то способ регистрации пользователя телеграм через код?
Есть библиотека telethon и там есть функция sign up о она не работает - [тут](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.auth.AuthMethods.sign_up)

Comment: почему не работает? В описании написано, что работает.

Comment: You must call `send_code_request` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны сначала выполнить send_code_request
Например:

```
phone = '+34 123 123 123'
await client.send_code_request(phone)
code = input('enter code: ')
await client.sign_up(code, first_name='Anna', last_name='Banana')
```